# Is it possible to add a comment in build.properties file used in sbt

Tags: sbt

Is it possible to add a comment in `build.properties` file used in sbt?

Say I want to add a comment like this to track which was the previous version I was using

```
#sbt.version=0.13.15
sbt.version=0.13.17
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can have single-line comments in the [`.properties`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties) file format using the `#` symbol.